# Bayesian Classification, example from Clojure For Machine Learning

Tags: clojure, machine-learning, bayesian

I am currently learning this algorithm for Bayesian Classification and when i was trying to follow along an example in the book i got these weird results which wasn't concise with the examples in the book.

I don't think my code is wrong (because i basically copied it by hand) but i still get results in the REPL which is impossible such as:

```
> (+ (evidence-of-sea-bass) (evidence-of-salmon)) 
==> 2.8139728009700775
```

It should return 1.000... with a small floating point precision error.

Here is the code:

```
(defn make-sea-bass []
  #{:sea-bass
    (if (< (rand) 0.2) :fat :thin)
    (if (< (rand) 0.7) :long :short)
    (if (< (rand) 0.8) :light :dark)})

(defn make-salmon []
  #{:salmon
    (if (< (rand) 0.8) :fat :thin)
    (if (< (rand) 0.5) :long :short)
    (if (< (rand) 0.3) :light :dark)})

(defn make-sample-fish []
  (if (< (rand) 0.3) (make-sea-bass) (make-salmon)))

(def fish-training-data
  (for [i (range 10000)] (make-sample-fish)))

(defn probability
  [attribute & {:keys
                [category prior-positive prior-negative data]
                :or {category nil
                     data fish-training-data}}]
  (let [by-category (if category
                    (filter category data)
                    data)
        positive (count (filter attribute by-category))
        negative (- (count by-category) positive)
        total (+ positive negative)]
    (/ positive negative)))

(defn evidence-of-salmon [& attrs]
  (let [attr-prob (map #(probability % :category :salmon) attrs)
        class-and-attr-prob (conj attr-prob (probability :salmon))]
    (float (apply * class-and-attr-prob))))

(defn evidence-of-sea-bass [& attrs]
  (let [attr-prob (map #(probability % :category :sea-bass) attrs)
        class-and-attr-prob (conj attr-prob (probability :sea-bass))]
    (float (apply * class-and-attr-prob))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect the result to be 1.0 then your probability fn result should be `(/ positive total)`

Comment: Nice thanks :) I guess I blindly accepted the author to present the correct and related code to the examples..